# Save data temporarily during a form

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to find out how long it takes the user to fill out a form.

My solution was to send the start time and put it in the form as a hidden input, but that means that the user could modify it and cheat.

Do you have any better ideas?

In PHP, I would use something like `$_SESSION` but I found nothing like this in Java spring boot.

Thanks.

Comment: Now if only have would have a [`HttpSession`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).

Comment: A real example would be much appreciated. Is it just by getting ``request.getSession()`` ?

Comment: Since you're using Spring Boot look at session attributes; https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-session-attributes. Also checkout model attributes; https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation#:~:text=The%20%40ModelAttribute%20is%20an%20annotation,submitted%20from%20a%20company's%20employee.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you could add event listener on keypress, change, click and assign date of this event to variable.
Then you could add another one event listener and assign another Date value on submit , the difference is the time you were looking for.

what do you think about this solution ?

Comment: This is front end data, therefore could be manipulated by the user. That would work but not very secure?